# R : Taking sum of row on a condition in a loop

Tags: r, for-loop, rowsum

I have a dataframe which looks somewhat like this :

```
inter_cv_vars <- data.frame( 
I_Org_ZB1 = rep(0:1,each = 2, len = 20),
I_Org_ZB2 = rep(0:1,each = 1, len = 20),
I_Org_ZB3 = rep(0:1,each = 3, len = 20),
I_Org_ZB4 = rep(0:1,each = 4, len = 20),
I_Org_ZB5 = rep(0:1,each = 5, len = 20),
I_Org_ZB6 = rep(0:1,each = 1, len = 20),
I_Org_ZB7 = rep(0:1,each = 3, len = 20),
I_Org_ZB8 = rep(0:1,each = 2, len = 20),
I_Org_ZB9 = rep(0:1,each = 4, len = 20),
I_Org_ZB10 = rep(0:1,each = 6, len = 20),
I_Org_ZB11 = rep(0:1,each = 2, len = 20),
I_Org_ZB12 = rep(0:1,each = 1, len = 20))
```

I want to create a new column "`O_ZERO_BILLING_CNT_TRL_Y1`" in this dataframe based on a condition that:

The summation of the continuous "1" value starting from column "`I_Org_ZB1`", if the sequence break then the value of the column "`O_ZERO_BILLING_CNT_TRL_Y1`" will be the sequence till the continous "1" value occured.

Eg:- If value of `I_Org_ZB1 I_Org_ZB2 I_Org_ZB3`  is 1,1,1 n every other value is zero then the column "`O_ZERO_BILLING_CNT_TRL_Y1`" value will be 3 but if the value is 1,0,1 & every other column is 0 then the value of "`O_ZERO_BILLING_CNT_TRL_Y1`" will be 1. If in a particular row all value is 1 then the value of column will be 12.

I have tried the below code:

```
for (i in 1:12){

if(i == 12)
{next}

ifelse(inter_cv_vars$I_Org_ZB1 == 1,

inter_cv_vars$O_ZERO_BILLING_CNT_TRL_Y1 <- ifelse(

rowSums(inter_cv_vars[,1:eval(parse(text=sprintf("(12-%s+1)",i)))]) == eval(parse(text=sprintf("(12-%s+1)",i))),

eval(parse(text=sprintf("(12-%s+1)",i))),0),

0)

}
```

But getting a wrong answer, could anyone point out the mistake which I made or provide any other alternative.

Thanks in advance your help :)

Regards,

Amit

Comment: Suppose you have two sets of `1 1 1` and `1 1 1 1 1` in a row.  What would be the expected value?  It would have been helpful if you show the expected result based on the example data.

Comment: Not much clear, but are you looking for something like `apply(inter_cv_vars,1,function(x) max(cumsum(x)*cumprod(x)))`?

Comment: @arun: result would be 3 & 5 for the column "O_ZERO_BILLING_CNT_TRL_Y1" but if the value will be 111101 then it will be 4 , i.e continous value of "1" in a row.

Comment: I am not sure I understand this properly.  Perhaps, `apply(inter_cv_vars,1,function(x) with(rle(!!x), lengths[values]))`

Comment: @nicola : Thanks a lot :).....Ya that's the exact function i was looking for ......thanks again....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is far from being optimized, but it should work if I got what you need:

```
apply(inter_cv_vars,1,function(x) max(cumsum(x)*cumprod(x)))
#[1] 0 0 1 3 0 0 1 2 0 0 1 3 0 0 1 9 0 0 1 2
```